# Ajax call data is not being passed to the controller during a POST

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

**Background:** I have a jQuery Kendo data grid where I am allowing users to do batch update functionality. I am attempting to call my controller through an AJAX call in jQuery. The issue I am facing is that my model never gets passed to the controller method. When my breakpoint hits on Controller it comes with count of 0 with MyModel items. Even though I can see my model in Fiddler body of request it actually never makes it to the controller.  This issue doesn't come up when I hit the API directly through Fiddler even when I pass in the same model which the application generates. What am I missing ? I am leaning towards something wrong with my AJAX request.

**Below is my controller code:**

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("UpdateRequest")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(List<MyModel>))]
    public HttpResponseMessage UpdateRequest([FromBody] List<MyModel> items)
    {
        var p = new GridItemProcessor();
        var r = p.UpdateRows(items);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, r);
    }
```

**Below is my ajax call code:**

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST", async: false, url: baseAPIURL + "MrrRequest/UpdateRequest",
                    timeout: 15000,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                    data: {
                        items: JSON.stringify(options.data.models)
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        options.success(result);
                        return true;
                    },
                    complete: function (data) {

                        $("#myGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();

                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                        options.error();
                    }
                });
```

**Below is how my json request looks like**

```
   [
  {
    "RequestId": 40,
    "beneClaimId": 32,
    "claimId": "20211308068186",
    "lineCnt": "1",
    "medRecRequested": true,
    "eobChk": true,
    "clmChk": true,
    "dateReceived": null,
    "MedRecRcvd": {
      "MedRecRcvdId": "I",
      "MedRecRcvdName": "Incomplete"
    }
  }
]
```

**Below is what MyModel looks like**

```
 public class MyModel
{
    public int RequestId { get; set; }
    public int beneClaimId { get; set; }
    public string claimId { get; set; }
    public string lineCnt { get; set; }
    public bool? medRecRequested { get; set; }
    public bool? eobChk { get; set; }
    public bool? clmChk { get; set; }
    public string dateReceived { get; set; }
    public ViewModel.MedRecRcvd MedRecRcvd { get; set; } = new MedRecRcvd();
}

   public class MedRecRcvd
    {
        public string MedRecRcvdId { get; set; }
        public string MedRecRcvdName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You send a list of strings `data: { items: JSON.stringify(options.data.models) },` but your controller expects a list of objects.

Comment: how do i send list of objects then? Take off JSON.stringify ? @ChristophLütjen

Comment: Use below syntax data: JSON.stringify(options.data.models)

Comment: @RahulShukla I tried that and still the items count in controller comes back as 0

Comment: This should work for data: '{items ' + JSON.stringify(options.data.models) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Comment: I just tried it, I still get items count of 0. @RahulShukla

Comment: Remove the [ResponseType(typeof(List<MyModel>))] from your controller and try, other than that all values seems good

Comment: That did not work either @RahulShukla. I think something is wrong with my controller method. What Christopher was mentioning earlier. Controller is expecting list of objects and I am sending list of strings through my ajax. I am not sure how to proceed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236980/discussion-between-heretolearn-and-rahul-shukla).

Comment: @RahulShukla jQuery will serialize js object, so `JSON.stringify` makes no sense here but is the source of the problem.

Comment: Please post your request body and definition for `MyModel`. When checking the request (e.g. in your browser's network panel) note the difference between `[{"prop":"val"}]` which is a json list of json objects, and `["{\"prop\":\"val\"}"]` which is a list of strings.

Comment: Hi @ChristophLütjen I have updated the question with the json request model and the C# model. By looking at the request you can tell I am sending a list of json objects. Do you think my controller needs to change to it accepts json object model ? I think my problem is somewhere in my controller code. Its looking for List<MyModel> and I am sending json list of json objects. I think we are almost there!

Comment: Great, you wrote that you have a working request "This issue doesn't come up when I hit the API directly through Fiddler". How does the working version look like? Note: If you are using a recent version of asp.net core using System.Text.Json json property matching is case senstive but there's naming strategy that expect "fooBar" in requests and will match it to "FooBar" properties (json standard to C# standard). You could try to disable this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-casing

Answer (score 1):

Your controller expects a collection of MyModel. Therefore you need to post an array of items. By using stringify you are posting a single string. As a test, if you changed your controller to accept 'string items' you should get a value in the controller.

Assuming your options.data.models is an array, you would post:

```
items: options.data.models
```

The properties on each item in that array need to match those on MyModel on the server. If that is the case, your posted data should materialise in the controller.

Comment: Hi @NigelK thanks for responding. I updated the question with my json request and C# Mymodel. I think my problem is somewhere in the controller code where controller is expecting a List<MyModel> items and I am sending list of json objects. I am guessing somehow Controller needs to accept json objects and then convert(serialize?) the json object to MyModel ?

Comment: The model binder does the work of converting / deserializing the posted data into the objects specified in the controller. That's all part of the MVC framework. Your posted data has quotes around the property name like "RequestId": 40. I think it should be RequestId: 40 ?